# Edit response codes for api's

Tags: python, api, response

I'll be using the [ConvertApi](https://www.convertapi.com/doc/response-codes) as an example. If I integrate this into my python code like:

```
try:
    #Calling API here
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

and get the response code

```
{
    "Code": 4013,
    "Message": "User credentials not set, secret or token must be passed."
}
```

is there a way I can print my own text. In my knowledge, I can do this

```
try:
    #Calling API here
except:
    print('It didn\'t work')
```

But I want to say "Check your connection" if I get `400 Bad Request`, "File failed to convert" for `500 Internal Server Error` and so on. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you calling it? If you can get a more specific exception perhaps it will have the response code as an attribute.

Comment: @PeterWood The response code looks like ```{
    "Code": 4013,
    "Message": "User credentials not set, secret or token must be passed."
}```

Comment: Edit the question. Make it great. See how to [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: @PeterWood I have just edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set up a dictionary where you create custom messages based on a particular response:

```py
errors = {'400 Bad Request': 'Check your connection'}
try:
    #Calling API here
except Exception as e:
    print(errors.get('e'))
```

According to the docs, it seems that you are only using the response header and thus not taking full advantage of the more fine grained message of the response body. In order to do this, you could follow something like this and maybe even avoid having to handle an exception or building your own dictionary:

```py
response = # Calling API here
if 'Message' in response:
    print(response['Message'])
```

Comment: If the actual response code looks like
```{
    "Code": 4013,
    "Message": "User credentials not set, secret or token must be passed."
}```
How can I create a dictionary with that?

Comment: If you think that the message provided by them is not fine-grained enough, then you can either go with the first suggestion with the response headers only, or build a dictionary based on the `Code`-key from the response body and print your custom message from that.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I like your solution because it's easy to understand. I just don't want to output to be in json format.

Comment: If you print the value from the dictionary it will result in a string. To use your example `print(response['Message'])` will be printed as `'User credentials not set, secret or token must be passed.'`

Comment: I got it! Thank you